# Рандомные значения из map сумма которых не превышает определённого значения

Tags: java, случайные-числа, map

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть класс Breakfast и метод eat() в котором получаю BMR и могу рассчитать калории для завтрака(caloriesForBreakfast). Есть map, где можно увидеть еду и соответствующие ей калории. Я хочу возвращать меню, которое состоит из рандомных значений названий еды из map, но сумма калорий в совокупности должна быть <= caloriesForBreafast. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста подсказать, как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

```
public class Breakfast implements Meal {

    @Override
    public void eat(int BMR) {

        int caloriesForBreakfast;
        caloriesForBreakfast = (int) (BMR*0.25);
        System.out.println("caloriesForBreakfast: " +  caloriesForBreakfast);

        Map<String, Integer> foodForBreakfast = new HashMap();

        foodForBreakfast.put("oatmeal", 356);
        foodForBreakfast.put("egg",150);
        foodForBreakfast.put("curd", 233);
        foodForBreakfast.put("bun", 240);
        foodForBreakfast.put("banana", 95);
        foodForBreakfast.put("sandwich", 340);
        foodForBreakfast.put("milk", 62);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
int tempCal = 0;
List<String> foodNames = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Map.Entry<String, Integer> randomEntry = entries.get(new Random().nextInt(entries.size()));
while (tempCal + randomEntry.getValue() <= caloriesForBreakfast) {
    tempCal += randomEntry.getValue();
    foodNames.add(randomEntry.getKey());
    randomEntry = entries.get(new Random().nextInt(entries.size()));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но почему ругается на randomEntry.value  и randomEntry.key, что Cannot resolve symbol value и Cannot resolve symbol key?

Comment: @Ksenia, исправил)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли! Работает! :)

Comment: @Ksenia, пожалуйста)